# Is the TypeScript type spec for && and || correct?

Tags: typescript

I asked this on the TypeScript forum a couple of days ago and had no reply, so I thought I'd try here.

https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/447628

The typeScript 0.9 spec says

> The && operator permits the operands to be of any type and produces a result of the same type as the 
>   second operand.

This is clearly wrong in the case of, say, `false && "123"`, which is `false`, which is not a string.

Can anyone comment on this?

**EDIT**  The linked question is not an explanation, it's a bit of friendly arm waving.  The spec. contains a formal error which it does not justify.  That is, a type rule should explain the type of *all* values of an expression in terms of its free variables.  The spec. clearly is wrong on this point.  I would consider any of the following an answer to my question:

- a justification from the spec. of why I should consider `false` to be a `string`;
- a pointer to where in the spec. it says that TypeScript's type system is not sound (in which case, what's the point?); or
- an acceptance that my point is valid and some indication of who I should talk to to have the spec. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

From the way typescript compiler sees it the Spec is correct.

e.g.:

```
var foo = false && "asdf"
```

The type inferred for foo is "string".

You can see it if you hover over foo in [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20foo%20%3D%20false%20%26%26%20%22asdf%22%0A).

It is somewhat an incorrect assumption. But there is actually no way of being *sure* what the actual type is going to be (e.g. when you have function calls in the chain, or even an *any* ). In this respect typescript ***assumes*** the developer knows what he is doing and the last one is what he really wants to use.

Comment: That is just wrong on the part of the TypeScript designers.  The least upper bound of two arbitrary types is `any`.  The point of a type system is that it should completely specify the family of values a given expression can have.  In this case, the typing rule (and the compiler implementation) are apparently both wrong.